# Need a line of code for a batch file to open another program and then close the original batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am writing a series of batch files to demonstrate to my class what a computer virus can do. All I need is a **SIMPLE** line of code that will open another file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@echo off
echo One
start notepad.exe
exit
echo Two
```

It will echo "One", start notepad, then exit the Command Prompt in which it's running.  It won't echo "Two".

If you want to open a document (or a web page, or whatever) rather than an executable, just specify its pathname in place of "notepad.exe" and `start` will do the right thing.

If you don't want to close the Command Prompt, but just want to end the execution of the batch script, do this:

```
@echo off
echo One
start notepad.exe
goto :eof
echo Two
```

That will return you to the prompt without echoing "Two".

Comment: You can use `goto :eof` to avoid the need to define a label at the end of the batch file. The first code is very likely wrong in nearly all circumstances. Most people don't like their console being closed from under them if they work interactively.

Comment: @Joey - thanks for the `goto :eof` tip - edited appropriately.  As for `exit`, it's how I read "and then close the original batch file". It's also consistent with "demonstrate [...] a computer virus".  Most people don't like those either.  :-)

Comment: Well, closing the batch file is something else than closing the console window. Reading the question now again I agree, it's a bit ... weird ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well here is how to open another executable but what do you mean close the original batch file?

start /d C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

and then to exit early you could just use exit. but if you reach the end of the batch it may just close anyway.